# Parse Error - Signature Version Selection Android

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-error, android-7.0-nougat

I have uploaded successfully 2 versions of my application, Now I want to upgrade with new version.

I am little bit confused with **Signed APK Dialog** as below:

[image]

This option is available since last couple of days but I didn't get why it is so?

What is **v1 and v2** and when we have to change it. I have tried to select second option but It gives me an error like :

[image]

Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

v2 is Android's new Signature scheme introduced in Android 7.0. More information [here](https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/index.html#v2)

Answer (score 0):

The "V2 (Full APK Signature)" is a new app-signing scheme introduced in Android 7.0. According to the documentation, you can always use the V1 signing scheme to sign your app if your app doesn't build properly with V2.

> Although we recommend applying APK Signature Scheme v2 to your app, this new scheme is not mandatory. If your app doesn't build properly when using APK Signature Scheme v2, you can disable the new scheme. The disabling process causes Android Studio 2.2 and the Android Plugin for Gradle 2.2 to sign your app using only the traditional signing scheme.

More information here [APK Signature Scheme v2](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html#apk_signature_v2)